# How to show map with pushpin for given latitude and longitude in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary, latitude-longitude, pushpin

I'm new to windows phone 8 application. **Could you please help me how to show a Map with pushpin for the given Latitude and Longitude in windows phone 8.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will use a Grid inside a MapOverlay, and works pretty well...

```
 var textGrid = new Grid();
textGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition(){Width = GridLength.Auto});
textGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black){Opacity = 0.7};
var distText = new TextBlock();
distText.Margin = new Thickness(8,4,8,4);
distText.Text = <your text>;
distText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
textGrid.Children.Add(distText);

var textOverlay = new MapOverlay { Content = textGrid, GeoCoordinate = midwayCoord };

var layer = new MapLayer();
layer.Add(textOverlay);
Map.Layers.Add(layer);
Map.MapElements.Add(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

To learn about maps and navigation [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
this is the official document from windows phone dev center. If you are trying to add some UI element to the maps refer this document [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207037%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).